# uniq elements from array of arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

I want to find unique elements from an array of arrays by the first element in the inner arrays.

for example

```
a = [[1,2],[2,3],[1,5]
```

I want something like

```
[[1,2],[2,3]]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-uniq) method takes a block:

```
uniq_a = a.uniq(&:first)
```

Or if you want to do it in-place:

```
a.uniq!(&:first)
```

For example:

```
>> a = [[1,2],[2,3],[1,5]]
=> [[1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 5]]
>> a.uniq(&:first)
=> [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
>> a
=> [[1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 5]]
```

Or

```
>> a = [[1,2],[2,3],[1,5]]
=> [[1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 5]]
>> a.uniq!(&:first)
=> [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
>> a
=> [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
```

If you're stuck back in 1.8.7 land where `uniq` doesn't take a block, then you can do it this way:

```
a.group_by(&:first).values.map(&:first)
```

For example:

```
>> a = [[1,2],[2,3],[1,5]]
=> [[1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 5]]
>> a.group_by(&:first).values.map(&:first)
=> [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
```

Thanks for the extra prodding [Jin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/521209/jin).

Comment: Note: I was trying this out in 1.8.7 and wondered why it wasn't working. Found out that passing a block to `uniq` was added in Ruby 1.9.2, as stated here. http://rbjl.net/27-new-array-and-enumerable-methods-in-ruby-1-9-2-keep_if-chunk.

Comment: @Jin: Right, I added a 1.8.7 compatible version for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a ruby 1.8.7 solution

```
irb> [[1,2],[2,3],[1,5]].inject([]) { |memo,x| memo << x unless memo.detect { |item| item.first == x.first }; memo }
=> [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
```

You could also take the shorthand over a hash and be a bit lazy and take the last item instead

```
irb> [[1,2],[2,3],[1,5]].inject({}) { |memo,x| memo[x.first] = x; memo }.map { |x| x.last }
=> [[1, 5], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: Something like `[[1,2],[2,3],[1,5]].inject({}) { |memo,x| memo[x.first] ||= x; memo }.values` would be another option (since we're only dealing with numbers in the arrays) and would probably faster than my fancy 1.8.7 version (not that the speed difference would matter much of course).